# Where are Android Studio's vector assets "physically" located

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio offers the option to add Vector Assets to a project. It does so using the following dialog which is opened via context menu `New -> Vector Asset` of the `drawable` folder:

[image]

Clicking on the `Clip Art` button opens a dialog where I can browse a library of vector images:

[image]

My question now is: Where are those resources actually coming from physically?

Are they stored somewhere on the file system (Android SDK folder, Android Studio installation folder)? Are they downloaded from somewhere?

My interest here is purely understanding where Android Studio is getting those vector images from.

It seems that I can download all those vector images from https://github.com/google/material-design-icons. That is not what I'm asking. The question is whether Android Studio has a private copy somewhere and presents those in the dialog shown above.

Answer (score 0):

They are readily present in your SDK folder to find those resources head to

```
\path-of-your-android-sdk-folder\platforms\android-xx\data\res
```

Usually the path of your android-sdk will be (if unchanged).

```
C:\Users\**username**\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
```

Comment: At first I thought that this must be the location as well. However, I cannot confirm this. Simply adding the first Vector Asset icon ("3D rotation") shows me the name "ic_3d_rotation_black_24dp". That filename does not exist in the Android SDK. However, it is clearly available in Google's `material-design-icons` repository. So, that cannot be the correct location.